# Git Clone Magento cloud

Tags: magento2

Hi. I'm trying to clone my repository in magento-cloud, but it's cloning some folders and not others, what could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Some folders are not tracked by git.
Do you try composer install after cloning ?

Answer (score 0):

After Clone, run the command on the project root through CLI

> composer install

After completing the command execution you can see all files.